# Declaring Variables within Array

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop

So i'm having some issues declaring a variable with an array.
I want to have the two variables (STATUS and CONSUMERS) be determined for each iteration of the array.

```
#!/bin/bash
QUEUE=( outbound.queue, inbound.queue, outbound.queue.optin )
DATE="$(date)"
MESSAGE="${QUEUE[$i]} is active with no Consumers at $DATE"
DESC="Please check rabbitmq for info on $HOSTNAME"
ALIAS="${QUEUE[$i]} $HOSTNAME"

for i in "${QUEUE[@]}"; do

    STATUS[$i]=$(sudo /usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl list_queues name status | grep "^${QUEUE[@]}\s" | sed "s/${QUEUE[@]}\s//")
    CONSUMERS[$i]=$(sudo /usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl list_queues name consumers | grep "^${QUEUE[@]}\s" | sed "s/${QUEUE[@]}\s//")

    if  [ "${STATUS[$i]}" = "running" ];
            then
            echo "$QUEUE[$i] is running";
                    if [ "${CONSUMERS[$i]}" = "0" ];
                    then
            lamp createAlert;
                    fi
            else
                    echo "$QUEUE is not running";
    fi
done
```

What ends up happening at the moment is it will either( depending on @ or * being in $QUEUE[]) attempt to use all of the variables at once, or comes back with
 `line 13: outbound.queue: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".queue")`

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: echo "$QUEUE[$i] is running" is WRONG because you must use braces: ${QUEUE[$i]}

Answer (score 0):

Some comments inside your code; I couldn't check but hope it helps.

```
#!/bin/bash

# remove commas from the list; separator is blank
QUEUE=(outbound.queue inbound.queue outbound.queue.optin)
DATE="$(date)"

# i is undefined. Use a printf at the time i is known.
MESSAGE="${QUEUE[$i]} is active with no Consumers at $DATE"
DESC="Please check rabbitmq for info on $HOSTNAME"
ALIAS="${QUEUE[$i]} $HOSTNAME"

for i in "${QUEUE[@]}"; do

    STATUS[$i]=$(sudo /usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl list_queues name status | grep "^${QUEUE[@]}\s" | sed "s/${QUEUE[@]}\s//")
    CONSUMERS[$i]=$(sudo /usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl list_queues name consumers | grep "^${QUEUE[@]}\s" | sed "s/${QUEUE[@]}\s//")

    if  [ "${STATUS[$i]}" = "running" ]   # ';' unnecessary
    then
        # {} were missing
        echo "${QUEUE[$i]} is running"
        if [ "${CONSUMERS[$i]}" = "0" ]
        then
           lamp createAlert
        fi
    else
        echo "$QUEUE is not running"
    fi
done
```

I can't understand the value of `i` in the for loop. Is it an integer or a queue name?
If it is an integer you should write `for i in "${!QUEUE[@]}"; do` ; if it is a queue name then `STATUS` and `CONSUMERS` are associative arrays and you should declare them as such with `declare -A`.